# How do I run my Selenium IDE test cases in headless mode?

Tags: selenium, phantomjs, selenium-ide, automation-testing, selenium-side-runner

I am working on selenium IDE scripts and want to run the scripts in headless mode to do other stuff while smoke test are running in headless mode

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You could add a config file, default name is .side.yml

Here is an example of my config file:

```
capabilities:
  browserName: "chrome"
  goog:chromeOptions:
    args:
      - no-sandbox
      - disable-dev-shm-usage
      - headless
      - nogpu
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the below, has define in more detail. Hope you get the answer.

```
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/headless-functional-testing-with-selenium-and-phantomjs--net-30545

https://www.qafox.com/new-selenium-ide-chrome-browser-headless-mode-using-command-line-runner/
```

Answer (score -1):

Try specifying in your driver arguments as shown below.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--headless");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: This example is for Selenium written in Java, the request concern Selenium IDE